# JavaScript JQuery trigger("click") problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, incompatibility

I have a form split up into two parts. One part is for entering data and the following part is a list of the entered data. When I CUD an object in the form I want to update the list, I do this via a trigger:

```
jQuery("#magnifier").parent().trigger("click");
```

Due to the heavy use of Safari in my company I had to choose the parent otherwise safari wouldn't accept the trigger. The following code is generated by rails (V 1.2.3) and kicks off the update of my list:

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('list_section', '/input_form/reload_list',
{asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize('periode_form')}); return false;">
  <img alt="Magnifier" border="0" id="magnifier" src="/images/magnifier.png?1288947266">
</a>
```

Problem is in my company Safari and Opera are the most used browsers. I can get it to work for one browser but not for the other. Is there a way how I can implement this without a if opera else kind of yacki code?

Comment: I don't get it. Where in the code do you execute `jQuery("#magnifier").parent().trigger("click");`?

Comment: @philgiese Entering data into my form I save it to the backend (via json to a rails app) and when the JSON call was successfull I trigger another javascript part to update a list (that will then contain the submitted data). Was this helpfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a form on the page.  Based on the contents of the form, you want a list updated elsewhere.  This is pretty easy to do and should not require any goofy opera checks.  My check obviously doesn't have any AJAX, so you will have to fill in the blanks there.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q7u7f/

Comment: Thx for your input, problem was of some other kind but it was the problem was bloated up way too much. Simplified it down to more or less your solution..